# basic loop in R

Tags: r, loops, factors

Trying to create a loop to extract the categorical data from the columns 1:9 of my df:

Something like this seems to work, but the problem is that only the las i is returned. Something is missing to keep every output after the loop runs.

```
for (i in 1:9){
  as.factor(df[,i]) -> paste("Category_",sep="_",i)
  }
```

I would like to end up having something like this:

```
Category_1 <- df[,1]
Category_2 <- df[,2]
Category_3 <- df[,3]
...
Category_9 <- df[,9]
```

Comment: Why do you want nine separate vector objects in your global environment when exact data is nicely integrated in **one** dataframe? I am interested to know what operation necessitates this need.

Comment: I want to give them names so that I can call them separately in a large script where I'm plotting PCAs and dendrograms, with colored labels according to these categories.  For example in here:

 `x_category_1.pca <- 
     ggbiplot(prcomp(x), ..., groups = Category_1`

Comment: You can still call them from a dataframe column: `..., groups = df[,1]` or `..., groups = df$Column1Name`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `assign`

```
for (i in 1:9){
  cat <- paste("Category_", i, sep = "")
  assign(cat, as.factor(df[,i]))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `assign`. In particular:

```
for (i in 1:9){
  assign(paste("Category_",sep="_",i),as.factor(df[,i]))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No loop needed

First some example data

```
data(airquality)

df <- head(airquality, 4)
df
# Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
#    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
#    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
#    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
#    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
```

Rename columns

```
colnames(df) <- paste0("Cat_", 1:ncol(df))
df
# Cat_1   Cat_2 Cat_3 Cat_4 Cat_5 Cat_6
#    41     190   7.4    67     5     1
#    36     118   8.0    72     5     2
#    12     149  12.6    74     5     3
#    18     313  11.5    62     5     4
```

…and split data frame into individual vectors

```
list2env(df, envir=.GlobalEnv)

Cat_1
# 41 36 12 18

Cat_2
# 190 118 149 313

# .
# .
# .
```